# Expo build failed for IOS

Tags: ios, expo, eas

I'm trying to build an IOS build, I'm still getting this error, and I don't know what is the issue or how to troubleshoot it, here is the error:

The following build commands failed:
PhaseScriptExecution [Expo]\ Configure\ project /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/7ayyak-cufyumfrcggyxvdcbkhcbyoltimc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/7ayyak/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/7ayyak.build/Release-iphoneos/7ayyak.build/Script-429C57D6D9461A8B30297609.sh (in target '7ayyak' from project '7ayyak')
(1 failure)

how can I figure it out and